# How do you take a Screenshot of a website via .Net code?

Tags: .net, web, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screen shot of any given url using .Net code?

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: With which rendering engine? After all, different rendering engines will produce different results

Comment: webkit seems to be the most standards compliant

Comment: wow. didnt think it was so easy :)

Answer (score 5):

Just stumbled over this: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image.aspx

Maybe something you could use?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a third-party approach for this, not doing it yourself. If you insist, though, then the heavy-handed way is to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch a browser, then `GetDesktopImage` to get a screenshot.

I'm sure there's an easier way, but that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PlatformInvokeGDI32
{
    public  const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="DeleteDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteDC(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="DeleteObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="BitBlt")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, int RasterOp);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="CreateCompatibleBitmap")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc,int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="CreateCompatibleDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="SelectObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc,IntPtr bmp);
}

public class PlatformInvokeUSER32
{
    public const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
    public const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetDesktopWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetSystemMetrics")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int abc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetWindowDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(Int32 ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="ReleaseDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd,IntPtr hDc);
}

public class CaptureScreen
{
    public static Bitmap GetDesktopImage()
    {
        //In size variable we shall keep the size of the screen.
        SIZE size;

        //Variable to keep the handle to bitmap.
        IntPtr hBitmap;

        //Here we get the handle to the desktop device context.
        IntPtr  hDC = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDC(PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDesktopWindow());

        //Here we make a compatible device context in memory for screen device context.
        IntPtr hMemDC = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

        //We pass SM_CXSCREEN constant to GetSystemMetrics to get the
        //X coordinates of the screen.
        size.cx = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetSystemMetrics(PlatformInvokeUSER32.SM_CXSCREEN);

        //We pass SM_CYSCREEN constant to GetSystemMetrics to get the Y coordinates of the screen.
        size.cy = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetSystemMetrics (PlatformInvokeUSER32.SM_CYSCREEN);

        //We create a compatible bitmap of the screen size and using the screen device context.
        hBitmap = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

        //As hBitmap is IntPtr, we cannot check it against null.
        //For this purpose, IntPtr.Zero is used.
        if(hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //Here we select the compatible bitmap in the memeory device
            //context and keep the refrence to the old bitmap.
            IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr) PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

            //We copy the Bitmap to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, hDC, 0, 0, PlatformInvokeGDI32.SRCCOPY);

            //We select the old bitmap back to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);

            //We delete the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteDC(hMemDC);

            //We release the screen device context.
            PlatformInvokeUSER32.ReleaseDC(PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);

            //Image is created by Image bitmap handle and stored in local variable.
            Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

            //Release the memory to avoid memory leaks.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            //This statement runs the garbage collector manually.
            GC.Collect();

            //Return the bitmap
            return bmp;
        }

        //If hBitmap is null, retun null.
        return null;
    }
}

//This structure shall be used to keep the size of the screen.
public struct SIZE
{
  public int cx;
  public int cy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several 3rd party components that does this. Apparently it's not trivial, since things like Flash and stuff don't capture so easily, for example.

I've used [HTMLSnapshot](http://www.guangmingsoft.net/htmlsnapshot/help.htm) in the past and was pleased with it (it's not free, but pretty cheap).

I heartily suggest you don't waste too much time implementing this yourself because you're bound to end up redoing a lot of end-cases that these 3rd party solutions already handle.

Comment: I wonder if someone advised Larry Page and Sergey Brin the same :P

Answer (score 2):

I searched far and wide to find a solution to this problem and the issue with using the WebBrowser and other suggestions is that you need a lot of access to the box.

To date this is the best third party tool I have been able to find:

http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/

Their SEO is terrible, but I believe I found them on a forum or even Stack... I do own a license and what you get is just a single DLL you can reference. Passing a license to the constructor removes their watermark.

After a quick peek with ILSpy I believe what it does is that it interprets the HTML and dumps an image for your viewing pleasure.

**Usage**

*Saving A URL*

```
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot  _Obj;
_Obj = new WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot ();
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result _Result;
_Result = _Obj.CaptureWebpage("http://www.google.com");
if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured)
{
    _Obj.ImageFormat = WebsitesScreenshot.
        WebsitesScreenshot.ImageFormats.PNG;
    _Obj.SaveImage ("c:\\google.png");
}            
_Obj.Dispose();
```

*Saving Raw HTML String*

```
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot _Obj;
_Obj=new WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot();
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result _Result;
_Result = _Obj.CaptureHTML(
"<html><body><h1> Hello world </h1></body></html>");
if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured)
{
    _Obj.ImageFormat = WebsitesScreenshot.
        WebsitesScreenshot.ImageFormats.GIF;
    _Obj.SaveImage("c:\\test.gif");
}
_Obj.Dispose();
```

You can find more on their usage page. Found Here:

http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/Usage.html

Hope this helps !

Cheers!!