# Website screenshot thumbnail generator

Tags: web, screenshot

What is the solution to generate and store website snapshot thumbnails of a link/url in a server folder dynamically? Yes I am a PHP developer, I would like a similar solution like ffmpeg - which is dedicated to audio and video handling. Is there any traditional third party solution which talks to php through classes and solves the requirement. I have searched the web and got many confusing solutions and here asked for a concrete one from someone experienced in this regard.

Comment: You want teh codez? Have you done any research yourself yet? Do you care about which technology, which languages, which OS? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Related (although based upon your past questions, looks like you're a PHP dev): http://stackoverflow.com/a/653881/11912 Particularly the third paragraph: "I heartily suggest you don't waste too much time implementing this yourself because you're bound to end up redoing a lot of end-cases that these 3rd party solutions already handle."

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977753/online-service-to-scale-a-website-into-a-downloadable-image too

Answer (score 0):

Take web screenshot is easy using google api's

take a look code and live demo

[phpwdn](http://www.phpwdn.com/screenshot-webpage-jquery-google-apis/)

Comment: An answer should be self-contained and not just point to an external link.