# Online service to scale a website into a downloadable image?

Tags: web, screenshot, scale

Does anyone know of a service that will allow you to provide a URL that will rescale a graphic representation of that site and let you download the image.  I need a scale image of a website to overlay on a smartphone graphic and I don't feel like jumping through hoops to get a screen shot from my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.shrinktheweb.com/.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobilito](http://mobilito.net/) and [mobiilisivutesti.fi](http://mobiilisivutesti.fi/) use [Browshot](http://browshot.com/) to take a screenshot on a mobile device, and retrieve a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lot of captures http://www.snapit.io/ and http://url2png.com/ provide API's for this and work well. There's a lot of others out there that do the same. You can do free individual captures with most of them through a web interface. For example a fullscreen capture of this URL using snapit.io would look like

http://www.snapit.io/snaps?url=stackoverflow.com/questions/11977753/online-service-to-scale-a-website-into-a-downloadable-image

Most of these sites let you modify the capture options (viewport size, post-capture scale for thumbnails, capture delay, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another: http://www.website-screenshots.com It allows to set browser dimensions in options.